# Grouped Permission in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

Before I explain my scenario here is my code.

```
public class Permission extends AppCompatActivity  implements ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {
    public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10;
    Timer myTimer;
    TimerTask doThis;

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest locationRequest;
    int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;

    String[] permissions = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        /* TODO : Grant the following permissions
         * 1. Request Read External Storage OK
         * 2. Request Write External Storage OK
         * 3. Request Read Intenal Storage OK
         * 4. Request Write External Storage OK
         * 5. Request GPS (2) OK
         * 6. Request Camera OK
         * */

        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Intent standby = new Intent(Permission.this, standby.class);
            startActivity(standby);
        }

        Button btn_enable = findViewById(R.id.enable);
        btn_enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EnablePermissions();
            }
        });

        /* Check if permission is done */
        myTimer = new Timer();
        int delay = 0;
        int period = 1000;
        doThis = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (checkPermissions()) {
                    myTimer.cancel();
                    Intent standby = new Intent(Permission.this, standby.class);
                    startActivity(standby);
                }
            }
        };

        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doThis, delay, period);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean EnablePermissions() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        builder.build()
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // NO need to show the dialog;
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                //  GPS turned off, Show the user a dialog
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().
                    status.startResolutionForResult(Permission.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    //failed to show dialog
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Location settings are unavailable so not possible to show any dialog now
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output of that is this.

[image]

and

[image]

my question is how can i make it as one? I mean a group permission that will allow each one of it.

I dont know what to do. what Im pointing is to merge all permissions as one then if the users did not select the last one still it is ok.

sorry for the confusion. as based on my code the 1st permission enables 3 settings and the second one enables the location service. Basically both of them lies on the different dialog which makes it 2 appear two times. I want is to merge them as one group permission (based on 1st image) so it will use the one dialog a dialog that will let the user to enable the following (Storage,Camera,Location and Location Services)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code seems to be missing the [`onRequestPermissionsResult`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-response) method that would handle what happens after the user accepts / rejects the individual permissions. As seen in the link, you can use a switch statement and have logic for each permission, so you can decide which is optional and which is mandatory, and change the UI and application behavior accordingly.

Secondly, if what you are asking is whether all permissions (from multiple groups) can be granted in a single dialog box (as opposed to one for each group), then it is not possible.

According to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) :

> Note: When your app calls requestPermissions(), the system shows a standard dialog box to the user. Your app cannot configure or alter that dialog box. If you need to provide any information or explanation to the user, you should do that before you call requestPermissions(), as described in Explain why the app needs permissions.

Thus, in your case, the user would get 3 permission dialogs - one each for Storage, Contacts and Location permission groups.

The last dialog that prompts the user to enable location isn't related to permissions, it just toggles the setting for GPS.

Comment: i see, thanks for the info. but my question is. is there a permission that looks at the 1st one but when it is enabled it will act what is the output of the second one

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain just your requirement a bit more clearly, without any assumption about how to implement it? I don't understand what you mean by "it will act what is the output of the second one"

Comment: sorry for the confusion. as based on my code the 1st permission enables 3 settings and the second one enables the location service. Basically both of them lies on the different dialog which makes it 2 appear two times. I want is to merge them as one group permission (based on 1st image) so it will use the one dialog a dialog that will let the user to enable the following (Storage,Camera,Location and Location Services)

Comment: That's much clearer, thank you. As far as I know, there is no way to merge the two dialogs. The second one (Location Services) is not a permission dialog; it is generated using the `LocationSettingsRequest` builder, and it simply switches on the GPS. The best you can do is to call the second dialog immediately after the first, so that it seems seamless to the user.

Comment: is that so.. any other dialog? or maybe custom for all of them?